# nhibernate map a category contains top n product

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a question, that is "category class" contains many product class. but now, i have a CategoryService class that will implement find IList at the same sutiation every category only contain the top n of products, not all of products, what should i do? Give me a choice,thanks!

the code list:

```
 public class category
 {
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public int Categoryname{get;set;}
    public IList<Product> Products{get;set;}
 }

public class Product
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string ProductName{get;set;}
   public Category Category{get;set;}
   etc...
}
```

then have a domain service:

```
public class CategoryService
{
   private ICategoryRepository categoryRepository;

   public CategoryService(ICategoryRepository categoryRepository)
   {
     this.categoryRepository=categoryRepository;
   }

   public IList<Category> FindAll()
   {
     IList<Category> categories;
     categories=categoryRepository.FindAll();

     //and now i need categoryRepository find all category ,and every category contains top n product, what should i do;

   return categories;
   }
 }
```

Comment: What have your tried so far? What does any of your code look like? Help us to help you.

Comment: Thanks! My English is not good!

Comment: OK, how do you want the results? in a `DTO` class or as `Category.TopProducts`? Also what do you mean by TOP products, this is products that is grouped BY?

Comment: I want a result as Category.TopProducts, I use of the Nhibernate as ORM, and Automapper to map the domain model to DTO, can you tell me what shall i do that orm mapping and the class of CategoryService.FindAll() should do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = // it's your top
session.QueryOver<Category>
.Fetch(category => category.Product).Eager
.Take(count)
.TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
.List();
```